# Return first value in combo box within userform (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform, that when initilised searches for files on our server and populates a combo box via:

```
cmbReportDateTime.AddItem Format(reportDateTime, "ddd dd-mmm-yy hh00")
```

Does anyone know if I can retrieve the first value of the combo box (after the population macro has finished) later in the script.

I've tried things similar to the below (as suggested by other websites) but it doesnt work.

```
me.cmbReportDateTime.Item(1).value
me.cmbReportDateTime.ItemData(1).value
```

full code:

```
Private Sub populate_reportDateTimes()
DoEvents
Application.StatusBar = "Searching for archived files... Please Wait..."
ii = 1
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookups").Range("Z1:Z100").ClearContents
    cmbReportDateTime.Clear
    currentDateTime = Now
    reportDateTime = currentDateTime

    While reportDateTime > currentDateTime - 1
        report_hour = Hour(reportDateTime)
        If report_hour > 20 Then
            reportDateTime = Round(reportDateTime) + 20 / 24
        ElseIf report_hour < 7 Then
            reportDateTime = Round(reportDateTime - 1) + 20 / 24
        End If
        If Dir(r04Dir & r04Prefix & 1 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & r04Prefix & 2 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & r04Prefix & 3 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & r04Prefix & 4 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & r04Prefix & 5 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & r04Prefix & 6 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & r04Prefix & 7 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Uddingston_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Stockport_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Oldbury_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Leicester_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & duplicatePrefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd_hh00") & ".txt") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & unmasteredprefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & unpinnedPrefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & mismatchPrefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd_hh00") & ".txt") <> "" Then

            cmbReportDateTime.AddItem Format(reportDateTime, "ddd dd-mmm-yy hh00")
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookups").Range("Z" & ii).Value = Format(reportDateTime, "ddd dd-mmm-yy hh00")
            ii = ii + 1
        ElseIf Dir(r04Dir & "Archive\" & r04Prefix & 1 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & "Archive\" & r04Prefix & 2 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & "Archive\" & r04Prefix & 3 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & "Archive\" & r04Prefix & 4 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & "Archive\" & r04Prefix & 5 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & "Archive\" & r04Prefix & 6 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(r04Dir & "Archive\" & r04Prefix & 7 & "_GAS_*" & UCase(Format(reportDateTime, "dd_mmm_yyyy_hh")) & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Uddingston_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Stockport_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Oldbury_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(stpDir & stpPrefix & "Leicester_" & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmddhh") & "*.csv") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & "archive\" & duplicatePrefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd_hh00") & ".txt") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & "archive\" & unmasteredprefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & "archive\" & unpinnedPrefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt") <> "" And _
            Dir(feedsDir & "archive\" & mismatchPrefix & Format(reportDateTime, "yyyymmdd_hh00") & ".txt") <> "" Then

            cmbReportDateTime.AddItem Format(reportDateTime, "ddd dd-mmm-yy hh00") & " (archive)"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookups").Range("Z" & ii).Value = Format(reportDateTime, "ddd dd-mmm-yy hh00")
            ii = ii + 1
        End If
            reportDateTime = reportDateTime - 1 / 24
    Wend
Application.StatusBar = "Search Complete!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All right here you go

```
Public thestuff As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Stuff1"
        .AddItem "Stuff2"
        .AddItem "Stuff3"
        .AddItem "Stuff4"
    End With

    thestuff = ComboBox1.List(0)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Debug.Print ; thestuff
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = thestuff
End Sub
```

This fixes the issue and gets you what you wanted. Notice "thestuff" was posted above the modules where it needs to be referenced.

Comment: Hi Doug, I tried    `Debug.Print Me.cmbReportDateTime.ListIndex = 0` to see what the value would return and it says "False"

Comment: Just so I'm clear - after re-reading my post I didnt think it made sense. I dont want the combo box to display the first entry, I just want to retrieve the value of the first entry, while the box itself remains blank for the user until the user selects a value themselves.

Comment: well the first value of a combobox is always zero. a blank section is -1 and so on and so forth

Comment: I think because the box is blank by default, it will always return -1. rather than `ListIndex = 0` i probably require something like `ListIndex(0).value` to get the value (obviously that doesnt work) - does that make sense?

Comment: alright i found an annoying work around, see edited answer

Comment: Hi Doug, The workaround posted above didn't work for me. The way I did it was adding the value the code is entering into the combo box to another "Lookups" worksheet. This isnt ideal but I have other reference points on that sheet so it isn't too much of an issue. I would have prefered a method of retrieving the value programatically. I think it's quite strange it doesn't seem to be possible. I don't think I've come across an element in Excel VBA before you cannot reference freely.

Comment: wait is this drop down in a worksheet or a userform? If its in a userform, the edited answer above works for me on many different drop downs

Comment: Hi Doug, its for a userform, I've edited my question with the full code as it stands now with the value being written to a worksheet.

Comment: here. if this doesnt help you then IDK what to tell you

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the response and your time. The code set out above inserts values in the combo box and `.ListIndex = 0` makes the default value of the combo box Stuff1 and then copies it to the sheet. Is that correct? If so this isnt what I was after - my apologies for the convoluted question.

What I'm after is: my code above populates the combo box with dates, once that has finished I want to call the first value of the combo box in another sub while the combo box itself appears blank.

For the time being I have written the values to a worksheet. The workaround does work, but not ideal.

Comment: try this new and improved idea. obv adjust to your needs